# class not found after compiling as Jar file

Tags: java, class, jar, classnotfoundexception

There is a jar file already deployed and successfully running. And now we need to add a very small string in a class.

```
These are the steps so far i made:

1.) I already decompile/extract the jar into a folder. 
2.) Open a class file in JDgui(java file viewer).
3.) Copy the source code in notepad++ and save as fileName.java
4.) Compile that .java as .class via cmd.
5.) Compile the folder again as .jar file (the same as the old .jar which is running)
```

Now when i restarted Tomcat, run the system, then it showing the error:

```
ClassNotFoundException
```

When i open that jar file in JDGui the class is in it.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Make sure the name and package of the class file are the same.

Comment: How did you achieve the following :4.) Compile that .java as .class via cmd. without errors?

Comment: @BatScream - when i try to compile the fileName.java to .class usign javac in cmd, theres a lot of errors occur, then i debug all and come with a successful one. Then i created the .class file now. When i try to compare the new .class file with the old one, theyre the same except the variable used.

Comment: are u using netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

This is no doubt coming from the error you naming the class differently or placing it in a different package (different folder).

When you save source of the class in a Java file, make sure you save it in a folder that reflects its package, and also place the `package` statement at the beginning of the file, reflecting the folder structure properly.

Also note that if the class is declared as `public`, it **must** be in a file named after the class: `ClassName.java` else it won't even compile. So you saving it in `filename.java` will not work in this case.

Also make sure you get no comile errors when you recompile this java file after modifying it (else you will not get a result `.class` file).